# IE background-image svg issue

Tags: html, css, image, svg, internet-explorer-11

I exported my logo from *Adobe Illustrator* as `.svg` and I want to display it on my website as `background-image:url(name.svg);`

Altough it says that `background-image` url it's supported until *IE 8*

[**Can I use svg**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css)

I can't even see it work on this

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/estelle/sjjjb)

on *IE11* on my computer.

Is there any **JSFiddle** example of a working `background-image:url(.svg)` in > *IE10*?

Thank you!

Comment: have you checked SVG url instead of data?

Comment: try exporting it as `.svg` image instead of `data-url` or `svg-code`, also check this [**JSFidde**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/SJjJb/2285)

Comment: See my fork - it works on IE http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/c1u46cb5/2/

Comment: thank you all for the answers. The problem was caused by the server not returning the correct MIME type. It should have returned image/svg+xml but it actually returned text/xml.